# Django rest framework JWT not returning web token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have followed all the instructions specified at [Django REST framework JWT](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/). But when I use my custom user model for login, it doesn't work.

settings.py

```
...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Custom user manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), full_name=kwargs.get('full_name')
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()

        return user
```

Here is my views.py which I am using for login:

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if account is not None:
            if account.is_active:
                login(request, account)
                serialized = UserSerializer(account)
                return Response(serialized.data)
            else:
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Unauthorized',
                    'message': 'This account has been disabled.'
                }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': 'Username/password combination invalid.'
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: What is the error displayed to you? What isn't working about it?

Comment: There's no error. Everything is working like its not configured.

Comment: Did you check your installed apps?

Comment: Yes, also its working for the default login DRF login API (api-token-auth).

Comment: By default the token should be returned on a request to `POST /api-token-auth/`. How do you try to obtain the token?

Comment: I am using my custom DRF API end point for login. Actually, I assumed it to work as it works in case of session cookies.

Comment: Do you have the end point calling the jwt view?  ```url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),```

Comment: As specified [here](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/), use `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"abc123"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/`

Comment: you using jwt or authtoken ?

Answer (score 0):

Check installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
)
```

Comment: Yes, it does have an entry 'rest_framework'. Also, my DRF flows are working. Its just web tokens are not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Token) authentication is the `token` that is being generated using a specific algorithm.

For your `LoginView` to work properly, you need to:

1. authenticate a user
2. generate a JWT token by using the `rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler` method
3. add the generated token to the response payload

You can check out the source code of the DRF-JWT module to see how this is done, but unless you want to substantially modify the response payload (by including, for instance a serialized representation of a model that is unrelated to the User model), I would recommend you use the implicit authentication and adjusting the behavior with the existing module API.

Comment: Made changes as mentioned by you. I am trying to login to my custom login view but getting error {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."} even though default login API is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the django rest framework authtoken

you can do this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```